# Average number among mutually exclusive possibilities

Tags: probability

Let's say $x_0 = 0$, $x_1 = 4000,$ and $x_2 = 8000$

The probability of choosing $x_0$ is 47%, $x_1$ is 35%, and $x_2$ is 18%

Each possibility is mutually exclusive. I am trying to find the long-term average of evaluating this equation.

What I previously did was simply multiply all of the possibilities by their probabilities of happening, and add them together to get the average.

That gave me: $$4000 * 0.35 = 1400$$ $$8000 * 0.18 = 1440$$ $$1400 + 1440 = 2840$$

Is $2840$ the correct average of the result of this equation, or am I missing something in the probability math?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: The long term average means that there is a certain probability of going between the events. You need something called a transition matrix. I suggest you look for Markov chains.

Comment: @stuartstevenson There's no need for Markov chains here. The expected value is simply $2840$.

Comment: +1 for having asked a question by using MathJax *and* showing your thought process!

Comment: Thank you all for the help!